# Position tracking using multiple cameras, turn 2D locations into single 3D point

Tags: python, opencv, homography

First off, I have very little OpenCV knowledge.

I have an IR beacon on the top of my head. Using some webcams, I am able to get the (x,y) location of the beacon for each camera. If I put these webcams around my room, I want to be able to get my (x,y,z) position tracking in real 3D space in my room.

[Heres an illustration for what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IHD2.png)

I am trying to replicate this video: https://youtu.be/LpB0AteUH7A. The video is open source, so I've looked at his code and tried to modify it to work for me. However, I found that the values these functions are returning don't make much sense (like 0 for all of them, or negative values, sometimes it just errors and I dont understand why).

From my understanding, I would need to calibrate the software before I am able to get my location. Calibration would involve moving the beacon exactly 1 meter and telling the software to save those points for 1 meter, then do the same for a few more points and locations. I already have the camera's distortion/coefficients matrix.

I'm using python and opencv, and so far I have attempted to use solvepnp, triangulatePoints, perspectiveTransform but I don't have the matrix math understanding to know what these functions are doing.

```
def calculate3DPosition():

    world3DPoints1 = np.array([[[0],[0],[70]],[[100],[0],[70]],[[200],[0],[70]]], dtype=np.float32)
    world3DPoints2 = np.array([[[0],[0],[70]],[[100],[0],[70]],[[200],[0],[70]]], dtype=np.float32)

    Point2D1 = np.array([[[168], [335]], [[315], [240]], [[430], [166]]], dtype=np.float32)
    Point2D2 = np.array([[[400], [288]], [[300], [187]], [[225], [125]]], dtype=np.float32)

    projection_matrix1, position1 = calculateProjectionMatrix(Point2D1, world3DPoints1)
    projection_matrix2, position2 = calculateProjectionMatrix(Point2D2, world3DPoints2)

    Point2D1 = np.array([[[168],[315],[430]],[[400],[300],[225]]], dtype=np.float32)
    Point2D2 = np.array([[[400],[300],[225]],[[288],[187],[125]]], dtype=np.float32)

    triangulationOutput = cv2.triangulatePoints(np.eye(4)[:3], projection_matrix2, Point2D1, Point2D2)

    mypoint1 = np.array([triangulationOutput[0], triangulationOutput[1], triangulationOutput[2]])
    mypoint1 = mypoint1.reshape(-1, 3)
    mypoint1 = np.array([mypoint1])
    P_24x4 = np.resize(projection_matrix1, (4,4))
    P_24x4[3,0] = 0
    P_24x4[3,1] = 0
    P_24x4[3,2] = 0
    P_24x4[3,3] = 1

    projected = cv2.perspectiveTransform(mypoint1, P_24x4)
    output = triangulationOutput[:-1]/triangulationOutput[-1]
    return output

def calculateProjectionMatrix(listPoint2D, listPoint3D):
    camera_matrix = np.float64([[247.9139798, 0., 155.30251177], [0., 248.19822494, 100.74688813], [0.,  0., 1.]])
    distortion_coefficient = np.float64([-0.45977769,  0.29782977, -0.00162724,  0.00046035, -0.16351777])
    projection_matrix = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape(0,3,4)

    ret, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(listPoint3D, listPoint2D, camera_matrix, distortion_coefficient)
    rotM_cam = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0]

    cameraPosition = -np.matrix(rotM_cam).T * np.matrix(tvec)

    camMatrix = np.append(cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0], tvec, 1)
    projectionMatrix = np.dot(camera_matrix, camMatrix)

    return projectionMatrix, cameraPosition

print(calculate3DPosition())
```

Because I'm using his code, I don't know what its doing but I do know it worked for him. Help is appreciated, if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The camera intrinsic values and distortion parameters are for my cameras. Those point lists also represent actual points and actual pixel values my for situation.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].